# Can't update my $PATH variable MacOS

Tags: macos, unix, path

I'm using MacOS High Sierra and I am not able to update my $PATH variable. I have tried updating my ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc and even my ~/.profile files but none of these update my $PATH file. I even downloaded a GUI for setting ENV variables, that GUI does seem to be setting the variables but it can't update the PATH variable (damn).

The code I am using looks much like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

When I paste "export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:$PATH" into my terminal and write the command "android" I get the desired result but I obviously want this to happen all the time not just when I paste that in. When I start a new terminal session I just get "zsh: command not found: android". This is driving me nuts, any ideas?

Comment: Try adding those to /etc/profile (of course with sudo). The open a new terminal session and see if it works

Comment: @BogdanStoica yea that didn't seem to work and it seemed to then break some of the other env variables I had.

Comment: are you sure you are using the default bash shell? maybe you have another shell like zsh or fish? what's the output of `echo $SHELL` command?

Comment: @BogdanStoica yea I'm using zsh, echo $SHELL => /bin/zsh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your using ZSH as shell, you have to put those changes in **~/.zshrc** file not in .bashrc

Then issue a `source ~/.zshrc` to reload and it should work as expected